# Unable to add migration

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an initial migration which has run successfully, however, when I try to add a new one I'm told I cant because the migration is pending:

```
PM> Update-Database -TargetMigration 201511051706498_InitialCreate -ConfigurationTypeName MyConfiguration -ConnectionString "__My_Connection_String__"
cmdlet Update-Database at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
ConnectionProviderName: System.Data.SqlClient
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Applying explicit migrations: [201511051706498_InitialCreate].
Applying explicit migration: 201511051706498_InitialCreate.

PM> Add-Migration -ConfigurationTypeName MyConfiguration
cmdlet Add-Migration at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name: InitialCorrectLedgeringColumns
Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: [201511051706498_InitialCreate]. Apply the pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration.
```

I can see the migration in the database `__MigrationHistory` table:

```sql
SELECT [MigrationId] FROM [localacount].[dbo].[__MigrationHistory]
```

Gives:

```
MigrationId
----------------------------------
201511051706498_InitialCreate
    
(1 row(s) affected)
```

What's going on here?  Why can't I add the next migration?

Comment: Are you sure you're targeting the right database? In the `Update-Database` command you're explicitly specifying a connection string but in `Add-Migration` you're using the default connection string from the context?

Comment: @lc. That's it!  Obvious in hindsight.  Thanks, do you want to add it an an answer?

Comment: Sometimes it just takes another pair of eyes (or more coffee). Glad it was easy.

Comment: Often, it just takes typing the question out.  I don't know how many times I've started typing out a question and then spotted the problem and never submitted it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're targeting the right database and verify your connection string.

In your `Update-Database` command you have explicitly overridden the connection string, but haven't specified one for `Add-Migration`. The latter would then be using the default connection string from your context - presumably a different database.

Answer (score 0):

If You can't find the solution from anywhere then check module of entity framework in the project by write on NuGet Package Console 'Get-Module' and check their is more than one entity framework in your project.
Next Step is to write "EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration" on console after that you will seen on console is "cmdlet Add-Migration at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name:" give the name of migration out here and press enter
Next Step is to write "EntityFrameworkCore\Update-Database" and check the database is the effect seen in it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).